# OpenGL - Can't re-size a glutSolidIcosahedron()?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glut

I'm changing a shape bigger than default radius of 1 but doesn't seem to work; this is what I'm trying:

```
void glutSolidIcosahedron(GLdouble size);   
glutSolidIcosahedron(9);
```

It's ok I did it (shown below):

```
glScalef(9.0,9.0,9.0);
glutSolidIcosahedron();
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[glutSolidIcosahedron()](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node88.html#SECTION000128000000000000000) creates an icosahedron centered at the origin and with radius `1.0`. It does not take any parameters to adjust it's size or scale. So yes, the only way to resize it is to use `glScalef` or some other method for adjusting the current matrix.

Comment: as soon as i re-size it the light does not seem to hit it that's weird

Comment: When you scale an object it also scales the normals which can cause lighting issues if you don't enable `GL_NORMALIZE` or `GL_RESCALE_NORMAL`. See this [faq](http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/lights.htm#ligh0090).